# How to submit form and open Bootstrap modal at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, thymeleaf

I need to submit HTML(with Thymeleaf) form and open a bootstrap modal at the same time. In order to submit a form I set `type="submit"` in a button tag. When I need to only open a modal I set `type="button"`. And it works. But how to do these two actions with one button?

form with the button:

```
<div class="button-view">
    <form id="view-form" action="/view-modal" method="get">              
        <input type="hidden" th:value="${n.getId()}" name="viewNoteId">
        <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" 
                type="button">View</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

method in Spring Controller which submits the form:

```
    @GetMapping("/view-modal")
    public String viewNote(@RequestParam(value = "viewNoteId") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("noteToView", noteService.getNoteById(id));
        prepareHomepage(model);
        return "/fragments/view-modal";
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing with `type=submit` that you are submitting the form, thus forcing the page to reload.  You need to convert your code so that it submits via ajax and thus doesn't reload the page.  Alternatively, have something on the page load that shows the modal and set that when posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to submit your data via AJAX using an onclick function.

button example :

```
<button th:onclick="'submit(\'' + ${n.getId()} + '\');'" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal"
      type="button">View</button>
```

javascript example :

```
function submit(userId) {
    $.ajax({
        url : yourURLString,
        type : 'POST',
        data : userId,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success : function(returndata) {

        },
        fail : function() {

        }
    });
}
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView addUser(@RequestBody int id) {
        /////
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: How to convey `userId` to controller? Should use @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam? What viewNote() should return to not reload the page?

Comment: I think that first lines should look in this way `var userId = { stringId : id };` otherwise you lose `id` value.

Comment: I edited the answer to be correct. You don't really need to even create a map variable anyways since you're only passing a single variable. If you were passing more than one variable, you'd need to create a data transfer object in your server code, then JSON.stringify the map and set the stringified variable as the data for your AJAX.